# UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight is working but UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uigesturerecognizer

If I add a down gesture recognizer then it does not work, if I change it to UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight then it works.

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDownRecognizer =
      [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:_delegate
                                                action:@selector(statusViewDidDismiss:)];
    swipeDownRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [swipeDownRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownRecognizer];
```

Comment: Are you using a scroll view?

Comment: No, just a plain UIView

Comment: Ok this is very weird. Can you upload a minimal project where this occurs? I have no idea why the direction would make a difference. Do you have other gesture recognizers in your view hierarchy that might interfere with the swipe gesture? If so, try setting the delegate of the gesture and return `false` for `gestureRecognizer(_, shouldRequireFailureOf:)` and `true` for `gestureRecognizer(_, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy:)`. Also implement the other delegate methods and see whether they are called.